# Azure Pipelines ManualIntervention@0 not running

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline that dynamically creates jobs in a stage based on an object parameter in pipeline.

There is a requirement to manually intervene between jobs so that each one is executed manually.

There are approval checks on the stage itself but all jobs will then execute in parallel so this is not the behavior required.

The snippet of code from the stage is:

```
trigger: 
  - main

pool: 
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

- name: workspaces
    type: object
    default:
    
    - workspacename: 'Prod1'
      jobname: 'Prod1'

    - workspacename: 'Prod2'
      jobname: 'Prod2'

    - workspacename: 'Prod3'
      jobname: 'Prod3'
    

stages:
- stage: DeployToProduction
  jobs:
    - ${{ each workspace in parameters.workspaces }}:
      - job: WaitForApproval_${{ workspace.jobname }}
        pool: server
        steps:
          - task: ManualIntervention@0
            inputs:
              instructions: 'Please review the pipeline and approve for deployment.'
              onTimeout: 'reject'

      - deployment: DeployToProduction_${{ workspace.jobname }}
        #condition: succeeded('WaitForApproval_${{ workspace.jobname }}')
        condition: succeeded()
        environment: env-production    
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - checkout: self
                  clean: true
```

So the ManualIntervention@8 task appears to only work on release pipelines, not in this scenario.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-intervention-v8?view=azure-pipelines

And the suggested ManualIntervention@0 task, which should suit this scenario from my understanding based on documentation, throws error in Azure Pipelines as below:

**A task is missing. The pipeline references a task called 'ManualIntervention' with version '0'. This indicates that the specific task version can not be found. (job 'WaitForApproval_Prod1', step ''.)**

Comment: Just FYI, this is possibly an issue with indentation as I have managed to get the job running and asking for approval now, but the behaviour is still not exactly what I need. I will post answer once fixed. Thanks

Comment: Why is this getting voted down so much? Is there something misleading or wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we should use `ManualValidation` in a **YAML** pipeline instead of using `ManualIntervention`. To set the execution order for the jobs under **one single** stage, we need to tell each job which their own dependent job is.

Here is a sample for your refence.

```
pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest

parameters:
- name: workspaces
  type: object
  default:
  - workspacename: Prod1
    jobname: Prod1
    dependentJob: []
  - workspacename: Prod2
    jobname: Prod2
    dependentJob: DeployToProduction_Prod1
  - workspacename: Prod3
    jobname: Prod3
    dependentJob: DeployToProduction_Prod2
    
stages:
- stage: DeployToProduction
  jobs:
    - ${{ each workspace in parameters.workspaces }}:
      - job: WaitForApproval_${{ workspace.jobname }}
        dependsOn: ${{ workspace.dependentJob }}
        pool: server
        steps:
        - task: ManualValidation@0
          inputs:
            instructions: 'Please review the pipeline and approve for deployment.'
            onTimeout: 'reject'
      - deployment: DeployToProduction_${{ workspace.jobname }}
        dependsOn: WaitForApproval_${{ workspace.jobname }}
        environment: env-production    
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - checkout: self
                clean: true
```

[image]

In addition, you may consider separating the deployment jobs into **different stages** and enabling environment approval instead of using the `ManulValidation` task. Resources usage (pipeline environment `env-production`) will check approval for each stage. Meanwhile, if not defining `dependsOn` property for each stage, the stages will be executed in sequence not in parallel. Here is another sample for this scenario.

```
pool: 
    vmImage: windows-latest

parameters:
- name: workspaces
  type: object
  default:
  - workspacename: Prod1
    jobname: Prod1
  - workspacename: Prod2
    jobname: Prod2
  - workspacename: Prod3
    jobname: Prod3
    
stages:
- ${{ each workspace in parameters.workspaces }}:
  - stage: Stage_${{ workspace.workspacename }}
    jobs:
    - deployment: DeployToProduction_${{ workspace.jobname }}
      environment: env-production    
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - checkout: self
              clean: true
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alvin, I was on leave and completely forgot, apologies. I actually got the code working in the end and had it down to a syntax error but I can see now the change I made was as you suggested, to use ManualValidation instead of the other task so I will accept this as the answer. 

This solution looks a lot more elegant with the multiple stages but I am happy with a single stage as it covers all requirements for my use case and so far has had positive feedback. If I extend it further I will split into stages as suggested. Thank you for help!